# How do I get the radio button data with php

Tags: php, radio-button

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio"><label for="radio1">Section 1 </label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio"><label for="radio2">Section 2 </label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio"><label for="radio3">Section 3 </label>
<input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radio"><label for="radio4">Section 4 </label>
<input type="radio" id="radio5" name="radio"><label for="radio5">Section 5 </label>
```

```
if (radiobuttun == section1)
  {
  include ("file1.php")
  }
elseif (radiobuttun == section2)
  {
  include ("file2.php")
  }
  .
  .
  . -->
```

Comment: Mir, this question has been asked and answered dozens of times on this site and elsewhere. If you update your question to show us what you have tried and where that attempt failed, we may be able to provide specific direction for your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the form is submitted via POST, the variable you're looking for is $_POST["radio"].